# How to select all a pseudo-classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've a button and I wanted to know if it is possible to make the css bellow shorter.

```
.button a:link, .button a:visited, .button a:hover, .button a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I mean maybe:

```
.button a:* {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Maybe there isn't any shorter way, but I just wanted to know.
I found something like this out:

```
.button a:link:visited:hover:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But it wasn't working, don't know why..
For information - I've general css for a in the top of the file:

```
a:link {
    color: #DA5632;
}
a:visited {
    color: #CE3408;
}
a:hover {
    color: #289BF8;
}
a:active {
    color: #CE3408;
}
```

So the button class a should overwrite the main a css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.button a` is all you need

I always set a default style on `a`, and target pseudo classes only when I need to have a different effect.

**Edit to include fix from comments:**

Because a default style for the a element is declared like:

```
a:link {
    color: #DA5632;
}
a:visited {
    color: #CE3408;
}
a:hover {
    color: #289BF8;
}
a:active {
    color: #CE3408;
}
```

at the top of the stylesheet, we need to make it `body .button a` by increasing selectivity we increase the importance of the styles applied.

Comment: Hmm, yes I tried it, but the button class uses the general a:visited css. See in this screen shot from firebug: http://i52.tinypic.com/x69tf.png

Comment: You can do `button a:visited, button a:hover`, etc. If I am not mistaken, that should override the general 'a:hover' styles. Check out: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/index.htm for more info on CSS selectors.

Comment: Simply make it `body .button a` and this will solve your problem (by increasing your selectivity you make this style have precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try

make sure that your stylesheet has a rule for ".button a" - also make sure this stylesheet is included after the global one defining rules for "a".

If that doesn't work, try being more specific, as in: ".button > a", only selecting direct descendants.

If THAT doesn't work, while it's bad practice, you could always mark your styles as important, like so:

```
color: #fff !important;
```

this will demand that they are parsed last.